How to fix Outlook servers changing SMTP email body, invalidating DKIM body hash in the process?
When sending 'some' emails to outlook exchange servers,
the body is slightly changed for some reason.
Apparently the DKIM body hash check is happening after that change, thus invalidating the signature.
Here's an example raw email body content sent:
<!-- ####### HEY, I AM THE SOURCE EDITOR! #########-->\n<h1 style=\"color: #5e9ca0;\">You can edit <span style=\"color: #2b2301;\">this demo</span> text!</h1>\n<h2 style=\"color: #2e6c80;\">How to use the editor:</h2>\n<p>Paste your documents in the visual editor on the left or your HTML code in the source editor in the right. <br />Edit any of the two areas and see the other changing in real time.&nbsp;</p>\n<p>Click the <span style=\"background-color: #2b2301; color: #fff; display: inline-block; padding: 3px 10px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 5px;\">Clean</span> button to clean your source code.</p>\n<h2 style=\"color: #2e6c80;\">Some useful features:</h2>\n<ol style=\"list-style: none; font-size: 14px; line-height: 32px; font-weight: bold;\">\n<li style=\"clear: both;\"><img style=\"float: left;\" src=\"https://html-online.com/img/01-interactive-connection.png\" alt=\"interactive connection\" width=\"45\" /> Interactive source editor</li>\n<li style=\"clear: both;\"><img style=\"float: left;\" src=\"https://html-online.com/img/02-html-clean.png\" alt=\"html cleaner\" width=\"45\" /> HTML Cleaning</li>\n<li style=\"clear: both;\"><img style=\"float: left;\" src=\"https://html-online.com/img/03-docs-to-html.png\" alt=\"Word to html\" width=\"45\" /> Word to HTML conversion</li>\n<li style=\"clear: both;\"><img style=\"float: left;\" src=\"https://html-online.com/img/04-replace.png\" alt=\"replace text\" width=\"45\" /> Find and Replace</li>\n<li style=\"clear: both;\"><img style=\"float: left;\" src=\"https://html-online.com/img/05-gibberish.png\" alt=\"gibberish\" width=\"45\" /> Lorem-Ipsum generator</li>\n<li style=\"clear: both;\"><img style=\"float: left;\" src=\"https://html-online.com/img/6-table-div-html.png\" alt=\"html table div\" width=\"45\" /> Table to DIV conversion</li>\n</ol>\n<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</p>\n<h2 style=\"color: #2e6c80;\">Cleaning options:</h2>\n<table class=\"editorDemoTable\">\n<thead>\n<tr>\n<td>Name of the feature</td>\n<td>Example</td>\n<td>Default</td>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove tag attributes</td>\n<td><img style=\"margin: 1px 15px;\" src=\"https://html-online.com/images/smiley.png\" alt=\"laughing\" width=\"40\" height=\"16\" /> (except <strong>img</strong>-<em>src</em> and <strong>a</strong>-<em>href</em>)</td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove inline styles</td>\n<td><span style=\"color: green; font-size: 13px;\">You <strong style=\"color: blue; text-decoration: underline;\">should never</strong>&nbsp;use inline styles!</span></td>\n<td><strong style=\"font-size: 17px; color: #2b2301;\">x</strong></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove classes and IDs</td>\n<td><span id=\"demoId\">Use classes to <strong class=\"demoClass\">style everything</strong>.</span></td>\n<td><strong style=\"font-size: 17px; color: #2b2301;\">x</strong></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove all tags</td>\n<td>This leaves <strong style=\"color: blue;\">only the plain</strong> <em>text</em>. <img style=\"margin: 1px;\" src=\"https://html-online.com/images/smiley.png\" alt=\"laughing\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" /></td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove successive &amp;nbsp;s</td>\n<td>Never use non-breaking spaces&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;to set margins.</td>\n<td><strong style=\"font-size: 17px; color: #2b2301;\">x</strong></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove empty tags</td>\n<td>Empty tags should go!</td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove tags with one &amp;nbsp;</td>\n<td>This makes&nbsp;no sense!</td>\n<td><strong style=\"font-size: 17px; color: #2b2301;\">x</strong></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove span tags</td>\n<td>Span tags with <span style=\"color: green; font-size: 13px;\">all styles</span></td>\n<td><strong style=\"font-size: 17px; color: #2b2301;\">x</strong></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove images</td>\n<td>I am an image: <img src=\"https://html-online.com/images/smiley.png\" alt=\"laughing\" /></td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove links</td>\n<td><a href=\"https://html-online.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">This is</a> a link..</td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove tables</td>\n<td>Takes everything out of the table.</td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Replace table tags with structured divs</td>\n<td>This text is inside a table.</td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Remove comments</td>\n<td>This is only visible in the source editor <!-- HELLO! --></td>\n<td><strong style=\"font-size: 17px; color: #2b2301;\">x</strong></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Encode special characters</td>\n<td><span style=\"color: red; font-size: 17px;\">&hearts;</span> <strong style=\"font-size: 20px;\">☺ ★</strong> &gt;&lt;</td>\n<td><strong style=\"font-size: 17px; color: #2b2301;\">x</strong></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Set new lines and text indents</td>\n<td>Organize the tags in a nice tree view.</td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>\n<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>\n<p><strong>Save this link into your bookmarks and share it with your friends. It is all FREE! </strong><br /><strong>Enjoy!</strong></p>\n<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>

When i send this particular email message i expect the DKIM signature to verify successfully.
I also expect this part This is</a> a link.. to not change.
The observed behavior is that on of these dots was removed on outlook's side, and the DKIM body hash fails.
If i send the same email, with This is</a> a link.. part removed, everything works just as expected.
Is there something i can do to fix this?
